# From which log IPTABLES shows the byte count

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall

When the following iptables command is executed

```
iptables -L -nvx | head
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 283388 packets, 43757672 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  614539 67414385   INPUT      all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

We get the bytes transmitted over the particular rule in the iptables chain. Is there any log files, we fetch this data, just like we fetch the bytes transmitted over an interface ens33 from **/sys/class/net/ens33/statistics/rx_bytes** file.

Answer (score 0):

`iptables` data can only be queried via kernel APIs e.g. using the `iptables` utility. No user visible files exist under `/proc` or `/sys`.

There are daemons which can collect/log/show this data though, e.g. `ulogd`, `bpfmon` and others.

Comment: Is it the same for the `tc` command also?